How prevent moving of tables header while scrolling?
The header little moving up and down while vertical scrolling. I can`t use CSS sticky bacause my parent has horizintal sroll. Keep position of the header on the top of page while scrolling page (vertically).
Is it possible to do it?


const table = document.querySelector('.table');
const header = document.querySelector('.table header');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  const tableRect = table.getBoundingClientRect();
  const headerRect = header.getBoundingClientRect();

  // Проверяем, когда шапка должна прилипнуть к верхней части экрана
  if (tableRect.top < 0 && tableRect.bottom > headerRect.height) {
    const topOffset = Math.abs(tableRect.top);
    header.style.transform = `translateY(${topOffset}px)`; // Используем translateY для плавного перемещения
    //header.classList.add('header-fixed'); // Добавляем класс при фиксации
  } else {
    header.style.transform = `translateY(0px)`; // Сброс перемещения
  //  header.classList.remove('header-fixed'); // Убираем класс, если шапка не фиксируется
  }
});
.mobile-container {
 background-color: ;
  width: 30%;
   border: 1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  position:relative;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.table {
  display: grid; /* если поменять на table пропадает горизонтальный скрол, зато шапка таблицы фиксируется наверху */
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  width: 90%;
box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;

}



.table header {
  height: 2.625rem;
   display: grid;
  padding: 0.6875rem 1.25rem;
  color: #8C8C8C;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 15rem) repeat(2, 5rem);
  white-space: nowrap;

      column-gap: 1rem;
 
  z-index:10;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky; /* Используем позицию sticky */

  width: 100%;
  
 /*transition: transform 0.16s linear, opacity 0.16s linear; */


  div:nth-child(1) {
        display: none;
      }
  
}

.table main {
  > div {
    display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 15rem) 6rem;
      row-gap: 0.25rem;
      column-gap: 1rem;
      padding: 0.5rem 1.25rem;
border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    div:first-child {
        grid-column: 1 / -1;
        position: sticky;
        left: 1.25rem;
        z-index: 1;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: min-content;
      }
    
  }
  
  
}
<div class="mobile-container">
  <h1>Мобильная версия</h1>

<div class="table">
 
  <header>
    <div>Название</div>
    <div>Описание</div>
    <div>Цена</div>
    <div>Количество</div>
  </header>
   
  <main>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Телевизор</div>
      <div>Большой цветной телевизор</div>
      <div>1000р</div>
      <div>10 штук</div>
    </div>

    <main>
      </div>
    
    </div>




Stack Overflow is an [English-only site], it could be useful to translate the comments in your code so your question is more comprehensible

FYI: You can achieve sticky headers even when a horizontal parent scroll is necessary. JS is still not needed, even in that case.

<main>  should be closed with </main>, not with another  opening <main>

Fix Main closing tag


You don't need JS at all
Fix the border rules



* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mobile-container {
  width: 30%; /* DEMO ONLY */
  height: 300px; /* DEMO ONLY */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  width: 90%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.table header {
  height: 2.625rem;
  display: grid;
  padding: 0.6875rem 1.25rem;
  color: #8C8C8C;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 15rem) repeat(2, 5rem);
  white-space: nowrap;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  div:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
  }
}

.table main {
  >div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 15rem) 6rem;
    row-gap: 0.25rem;
    column-gap: 1rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.25rem;
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0; /* Improved borders */
    div:first-child {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
      position: sticky;
      left: 1.25rem;
      z-index: 1;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: min-content;
    }
  }
}
<div class="mobile-container">
  <h1>Mobile version</h1>
  <div class="table">
    <header>
      <div>Name</div>
      <div>Description</div>
      <div>Price</div>
      <div>Quantity</div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div>
        <div>TV</div>
        <div>Large color TV</div>
        <div>1000 rubles</div>
        <div>10 units</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>TV</div>
        <div>Large color TV</div>
        <div>1000 rubles</div>
        <div>10 units</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>TV</div>
        <div>Large color TV</div>
        <div>1000 rubles</div>
        <div>10 units</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>TV</div>
        <div>Large color TV</div>
        <div>1000 rubles</div>
        <div>10 units</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>TV</div>
        <div>Large color TV</div>
        <div>1000 rubles</div>
        <div>10 units</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>TV</div>
        <div>Large color TV</div>
        <div>1000 rubles</div>
        <div>10 units</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>TV</div>
        <div>Large color TV</div>
        <div>1000 rubles</div>
        <div>10 units</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>TV</div>
        <div>Large color TV</div>
        <div>1000 rubles</div>
        <div>10 units</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>TV</div>
        <div>Large color TV</div>
        <div>1000 rubles</div>
        <div>10 units</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>TV</div>
        <div>Large color TV</div>
        <div>1000 rubles</div>
        <div>10 units</div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>

</div>




I need only page scroll, i dont need internal vertical scroll in table, i cant use height for table, it can be 100% of height
